# Arrows from cloud cross the outer line

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm using TikZ to draw a cloud. Also I'm drawing arrows from the cloud to some nodes.
But the startpoints of the arrows are in or outside the cloud but not exactly on the outer line.
I think the picture shows my problem:

[image: a cloud with arrows]

As well here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[cloud, cloud puffs=15.7, minimum width=3cm, draw] (cloud) at (0,0) {Cloud};
    \path[->] (cloud) edge (2, 2)
          (cloud) edge (2, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you may think by yourself my question is how to position the start points of the arrows on the line of the cloud.

Comment: It's due to the fractional numbers of puffs.

Comment: I thought that as well. But is there a simple possibility to position the start points correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can either [use an integer number of puffs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91320/arrows-from-cloud-cross-the-outer-line#comment197315_91320) or the `intersections` library and find the points manually.

**Notes:**

- I used named coordinates for `(2,1)` and `(2,2)` to not repeat hard-coded coordinates.
- The anchor `.center` is neede because in the second example (the one to `(2,1)`) the `(cloud) -- (2,1)` does not intersect with the cloud’s border.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
        name path=cloud,
        cloud, cloud puffs=15.7,
        minimum width=3cm, draw,
    ] (cloud) at (0,0) {Cloud};
    \path[name path=path22] (cloud.center) -- (2, 2) coordinate (to22);
    \path[name path=path21] (cloud.center) -- (2, 1) coordinate (to21);
    \draw[->,
          name intersections={of=cloud and path22,name=from22},
          name intersections={of=cloud and path21,name=from21}
       ] (from22-1) edge (to22)
         (from21-1) to   (to21);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this simple solution. I think I will simply use an integer numer ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Of course Qrrbrbirlbel answer is the right one, but I cannot resist to post this cheat idea:
*draw the cloud shape after the rays, and use white fill*. This solution is much simpler if you have lots of rays to draw.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (cloud) at (0,0);
    \foreach \angle in {0,15,...,360}
      \draw[->] (cloud) -- (\angle:2);
    \node[cloud, cloud puffs=15.7, minimum width=3cm, draw,
          fill=white] (cloud) at (cloud) {Cloud};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: Try something like `\foreach \angle in {0,1,...,360}\draw (cloud) -- (\angle:2);` (`cloud` being the node not the coordinate!) and you will see that only the upper right part of the cloud (the asymmetric one due to the non-integer number of puffs) is the problem. [The `cloud puffs=15` border is clearly visible.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2E7Ed.png)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Right! Nice demonstration indeed.

Comment: You could also draw on a layer below the cloud.

Answer (score 4):

`@Dave` I never even thought of a non-integer number of puffs. You've stumbled on something that shouldn't work, but does. Obviously Qrrbrbirlbel provides the *proper* solution. But for fans of impenetrable hacking, here's something that also shouldn't work, but does:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usepgflibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter

% Save the original background path definition.
\let\pgf@sh@bg@cloud@original=\pgf@sh@bg@cloud

% Redefine the cloud background path.
\def\pgf@sh@bg@cloud{%
    % Draw the original path.
    \pgf@sh@bg@cloud@original%
    % Now save it globally.
    \pgfgetpath\tmp@path%
    % NB this will NOT work with early PGF versions as this
    % relies on \pgf@node@name
    \expandafter\global\expandafter%
        \let\csname pgf@sh@bg@path@saved@\pgf@node@name\endcsname=\tmp@path%
}

% Now redefine the cloud anchor border.
% NB Outer sep is NOT taken into account.
\def\pgf@anchor@cloud@border#1{%
    \pgfextract@process\externalpoint{#1}%
    %
    \pgfintersectionofpaths{%
        % Set the transform of the current referenced node.
        \pgfsettransform{\csname pgf@sh@nt@\pgfreferencednodename\endcsname}%
        % Draw a line from the center of the cloud to the the external point.
        \pgfpathmoveto{\centerpoint}%   
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\externalpoint}}%
    }%
    {%      
        % Install the saved cloud path.
        \expandafter\pgfsetpath%
            \csname pgf@sh@bg@path@saved@\pgfreferencednodename\endcsname%      
    }%
    \ifnum\pgfintersectionsolutions>0\relax%
        \pgf@process{%
            % Transform the intersection appropriately.
            \pgfpointintersectionsolution{1}%
            \pgf@pos@transform{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
        }
    \else%
        \centerpoint%
    \fi
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [cloud, cloud puffs=15.7, minimum width=3cm, draw]
    (cloud) at (0,0) {Cloud};

\foreach \i in {0, 10, ..., 360}
    \draw [black, ->] (cloud) -- (\i:5cm and 3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: cloud border intersections]

Note, that it doesn't take into account the `outer sep` and is likely not to be particularly robust, nor will it work with early versions of PGF. It is also *slow*.

Comment: *fans of impenetrable hacking* that would be me :) But there was [another question for asymetrical cloud puffs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45404/asymmetric-cloud-shape-in-tikz) which might be the reason for this question because on that question the asymmetry was achieved via nonineteger puff number.

Comment: @mwibrow Yes, I like hacky solutions as well :-) But for the my presentation I will use a simple one ;-)