# How to draw cloud shape in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I saw that Ti*k*Z can draw cloud shapes, even asymmetric ones: [Asymmetric cloud shape in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45404/asymmetric-cloud-shape-in-tikz).

But as I am not familiar with Ti*k*Z and prefer Asymptote's C++ like syntax, I would like to know how to draw cloud shapes in Asymptote.

Comment: Do you just want to draw a cloud shape, or do you also want to fit it to surround some text?

Comment: @CharlesStaats a cloud shape with optional text in its center.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

This module `cloudshape.asy` is an attempt to provide a class `CloudShape`,
which can be used to draw labels inside the cloud-shaped envelope
(code for the envelope is borrowed from the `roundbox` 
envelope routine from `plain_boxes.asy`):

```
// tested with Asymptote 2.35
//
// cloudshape.asy
//
import graph;

struct CloudShape{
  Label L;
  int n;
  pen borderPen, fillPen;
  guide base;
  guide cloud;
  pair[] CurlPoint; 
  real[] r;
  pair[] center;

  private real[] phi;
  private real a[],b[],c[];
  private real[] alpha;

  void makeRandomPoints(){
    CurlPoint=sequence(
        new pair(int k){
          return relpoint(base,k/n
           +1/3/n*(2*unitrand()-1)
           );
        }
        ,n
      );
  }

  void precond(){
    makeRandomPoints();

    int inext, iprev, sign;
    sign=1;
    alpha=array(n,0);
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
      iprev=(i-1+n)%n;
      inext=(i+1)%n;
      a[i]=abs(CurlPoint[i]-CurlPoint[iprev]);
      b[i]=abs(CurlPoint[inext]-CurlPoint[i]);
      c[i]=abs(CurlPoint[inext]-CurlPoint[iprev]);
      phi[i]=pi-acos(max(-1,min((a[i]^2+b[i]^2-c[i]^2)/(2*a[i]*b[i]),1)));

      alpha[0]+=sign*phi[i]/2;
      sign=-sign;
    }


    for(int i=1;i<=(n-1)/2;++i){
      alpha[i]  =phi[i-1]-alpha[i-1];
      alpha[n-i]=phi[n-i]-alpha[(n-i+1)%n];  
    }
    b.delete(); c.delete(); phi.delete();      
  }

  void makeCurls(){
    int inext, iprev;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
      iprev=(i-1+n)%n;
      inext=(i+1)%n;
      r[i]=a[i]/2/cos(alpha[i]);

      center[i]=extension(
        CurlPoint[iprev], rotate(-degrees(alpha[i]),CurlPoint[iprev])*CurlPoint[i]
       ,CurlPoint[i],     rotate( degrees(alpha[i]),CurlPoint[i])*CurlPoint[iprev]
      );

      if((degrees(CurlPoint[i]-center[i])-degrees(CurlPoint[iprev]-center[i]))%360>180){
        center[i]=reflect(CurlPoint[iprev],CurlPoint[i])*center[i];
      }
      cloud=cloud--arc(center[i],CurlPoint[iprev],CurlPoint[i]);
    }
    cloud=cloud--cycle;    
    a.delete();
  }

  void operator init(Label L="", int n=11
    ,guide base=circle((0,0),1)
    ,pen borderPen=currentpen, pen fillPen=nullpen){
    assert(n>2 ,"Expect n>2, but n="+string(n)+" found.");
    this.L=L;
    this.n         = n+1-(n%2); // ensure that n is odd
    this.borderPen = borderPen;
    this.fillPen   = fillPen;
    this.base=base;
    precond();
    makeCurls();
  }

  void operator init(Label L="", pair[] CurlPoint
    ,pen borderPen=currentpen, pen fillPen=nullpen){
    this.L=L;
    this.CurlPoint=copy(CurlPoint);
    this.n=CurlPoint.length;
    assert(n>2 ,"Expect n>2, but n="+string(n)+" found.");
    if(this.n%2==0){
      CurlPoint.push((CurlPoint[0]+CurlPoint[n-1])/2);
      ++this.n;      
    }
    this.borderPen = borderPen;
    this.fillPen   = fillPen;
    this.base=graph(CurlPoint)..cycle;
    precond();
    makeCurls();
  }

}

envelope MakeCloud(int n=11){
  return new
      path (frame dest, frame src=dest, real xmargin=0, real ymargin=xmargin,
                   pen p=currentpen, filltype filltype=NoFill, bool above=true)
      {
          pair m=min(src);
          pair M=max(src);
          pair bound=M-m;
          int sign=filltype == NoFill ? 1 : -1;
          real a=bound.x+2*xmargin;
          real b=bound.y+2*ymargin;
          real ds=0;
          real dw=min(a,b)*0.3;
          path g=shift(m-(xmargin,ymargin))*((0,dw)--(0,b-dw){up}..{right}
          (dw,b)--(a-dw,b){right}..{down}
          (a,b-dw)--(a,dw){down}..{left}
          (a-dw,0)--(dw,0){left}..{up}cycle);

        frame F;        
        CloudShape cl=CloudShape(n,reverse(g));      
        if(above == false) {
          filltype.fill(F,cl.cloud,p);
          prepend(dest,F);
        } else filltype.fill(dest,cl.cloud,p);

        return cl.cloud;
      };
}
```

It splits a `base` closed path into `n` points 
and builds a closed sequence of arcs. 
The nodes of the `base` path must follow counter-clockwise order.

A complete `MWE` (needs `lualatex` to use Humor-Sans font):

```
// Example
//   this example uses Humor-Sans font 
//   from https://github.com/shreyankg/xkcd-desktop
//
import cloudshape;

settings.tex="lualatex";

real w=8cm,h=0.618w;
size(w,h);
import fontsize;defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{fontspec}");

srand(1110011);

Label L=Label("{$\pi=\arctan(1)+\arctan(2)+\arctan(3)$}",align=plain.E);

draw("{\fontspec{Humor-Sans}Hello, World!}"
  ,MakeCloud(9),(0,1),xmargin=1mm,ymargin=3mm
  ,p=blue,filltype=Fill(paleblue));

draw(L,MakeCloud(39),(0.2,0),xmargin=5pt
  ,p=green, filltype=Fill(orange+opacity(0.5)));

draw(scale(4,1)*unitsquare,nullpen);    
shipout(bbox(Fill(paleyellow)));
```

**Edit**:
An example showcase:

[image]

```
%
% showcase.tex
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{asydef}
size(2cm);
import cloudshape;
pen basePen=orange+0.5bp;
pen cloudPen=darkblue+0.9bp;
void show(int n, guide g){ 
  CloudShape cs=CloudShape(n,base=g);
  draw(cs.base,basePen); 
  draw(cs.cloud,cloudPen); 
  label("$n="+string(n)+"$",(min(cs.cloud)+max(cs.cloud))/2);
}
guide[] case={
  scale(4,3)*unitcircle,
  (0,0)..(12,0)..(12,4)..(8,5)..(4,8)..(0,4)..cycle,
};
\end{asydef}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{asy}
show(7,case[0]);
\end{asy}
&
\begin{asy}
show(7,case[1]);
\end{asy}
\\
\begin{asy}
show(9,case[0]);
\end{asy}
&
\begin{asy}
show(9,case[1]);
\end{asy}
\\
\begin{asy}
show(11,case[0]);
\end{asy}
&
\begin{asy}
show(11,case[1]);
\end{asy}
\\
\begin{asy}
show(21,case[0]);
\end{asy}
&
\begin{asy}
show(21,case[1]);
\end{asy}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about support ellipse envelope? Is it possible to adjust the symmetry level?

Comment: @alick: In fact, `ellipse` envelope was the first try, 
but I replaced it with a `roundbox` since it looks
more suitable to surround a label - ellipse leaves 
long empty spaces on the left and right for relatively long strings.
Anyway, it's a proof-of-concept, 
addition of more envelopes is a straightforward procedure.
Btw, the `CloudShape` can already be used with arbitrary `base` path,
and the label can be drawn on top of it,
the envelope is just a convenient way to fit the 
label automatically.

Comment: Can you show us what it looks like with an outline only? (using `draw` rather than `fill`)

Comment: @Charles Staats: see example outlines added

Comment: This is great! Another suggestion: It might helpful if you could somehow ensure that every "curl" has radius less than the radii of curvature of the base path at its endpoints (computed using `radius(path, t)`). Since I don't understand the algorithm you're using to compute the radii, I can't tell how hard this change would be.

Comment: @Charles Staats: Each radius is uniquely identified
from the set of (more-or-less randomly) generated `n` points 
along the `base` path, so it is not applicable, 
at least in the current form. 
However, the curvature of the path 
probably could be used to improve the point distribution.

Comment: Could you not simply add a check that says "if the computed radius is too large, use a semicircle"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24099/discussion-between-charles-staats-and-g-kov).

Comment: @g.kov: Orange coloured shapes are beautiful. Is there a way to create such shapes without the cloud (or clouds can be white in colour) in tikz for pdfLaTeX?

Comment: @Khaaba: check out [Curve through a sequence of points with Metapost and TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54771/27243).

Answer (score 5):

**Major edit to improve my solution, incorporating the @CharlesStaats comment.**

The following `cloudpath` function creates arcs around the periphery of a non-intersecting cyclic path, then trims those arcs to one another with a call to `buildcycle`.

```
path cloudpath(path p, real minArcRadius, real maxArcScale = 1.0)
```

The arc radius is the second argument.  The third argument allows random perterbations of the arc sizes.

```
unitsize(1inch);

path cloudpath(path p, real minArcRadius, real maxArcScale = 1.0)
{
    real overlap = 0.9;
    real pLength = arclength(p);

    // create cloud arc radii
    real[] radii;
    while(2*overlap * sum(radii) < pLength)
    {
        radii.push(minArcRadius * (1.0 + (unitrand() * (maxArcScale - 1.0))));
    }

    // scale radii to avoid large arc overlap at beginning and end of path p
    radii = radii * (pLength / (2*overlap * sum(radii)));

    // create overlapping arcs exterior to path p
    path arcs[];
    real currentTime = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < radii.length; ++i)
    {
        pair circleCenter = (arcpoint(p, currentTime));
        path thisCircle = shift(circleCenter)*scale(radii[i])*unitcircle;
        pair[] intersects = intersectionpoints(thisCircle, p);
        path thisArc = arc(circleCenter, intersects[0], intersects[1], CW);
        if (inside(p, relpoint(thisArc, 0.1)))
        {
            thisArc = arc(circleCenter, intersects[0], intersects[1], CCW);
        }
        arcs.push(thisArc);
        if (i < radii.length - 1)
        {
            currentTime += overlap * (radii[i] + radii[i+1]);
        }
    }

    draw(p, red); // comment out to hide construction
    draw(arcs, mediumgray); // comment out to hide construction

    return buildcycle(... arcs);
}

path quadPath = slant(0.5)*unitsquare;
draw(cloudpath(quadPath, 0.2, 1.5), 2+black);

path ellipsePath = shift(4.0,0.5)*rotate(30)*scale(1,0.5)*unitcircle;
draw(cloudpath(ellipsePath, 0.2, 2.0), 2+black);

path crossingPath = shift(0,-3)*((0,0)--(2,0)--(0,2)--(2,2)--cycle);
draw(cloudpath(crossingPath, 0.2, 2.0), 2+black);

path concavePath = shift(3.0,-3)*((0,0)--(2,0)--(2,2)--(0,2)--(1,1)--cycle);
draw(cloudpath(concavePath, 0.2, 2.0), 2+black);
```

I didn't do much testing, so I'm not sure if the function is very robust.  As shown below, intersecting paths fail.  Comment out the `draw` commands in the `cloudpath` function to avoid drawing the red and gray curves.

[image]

Comment: For an explanation of the behavior of `buildcycle`, see pages 30ff of [the metapost manual](http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf). (The Asymptote `buildcycle` command was designed to imitate the Metapost command.) But it seems the command is really designed to be used when adjacent paths only intersect in a single point. in this case, I'd say you are better off trying to eliminate the portion of each circle inside the red trapezoid and only then applying `buildcycle`.