# How to use callouts behind the text With Latex like this?

Tags: tables, math-mode, graphics, geometry, installing-fonts

How to use callouts behind the text?
[image]

Comment: This is possible with tikz, but the callouts are all symmetrical and do not look like the one you are showing as an example. [Asymmetric cloud shape in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45404/138900)

Comment: Not exactly the design that you have asked for but maybe the [`todonotes`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf) package would be suitable for this purpose?

Answer (score 5):

Adapting this MWE (adapted from this [Simple speech bubbles, arrows or balloon like shapes in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38805/simple-speech-bubbles-arrows-or-balloon-like-shapes-in-beamer)) and using the math enviroment `\ensuremath`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.callouts}
\newcommand{\clouds}[2]{
        \tikz[remember picture,baseline]{\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]%
        (#1) {{\ensuremath{#1}}};\node[overlay,cloud callout,callout relative pointer={(-0.7cm,-0.2cm)},%
        aspect=2.5,draw=green] at ($(#1.south)+(4.2cm,1cm)$) {\ensuremath{#2}};}%
    }%

\begin{document}
\clouds{y'+xy=0}{\text{Being } \dfrac{y'}y=-x}
\end{document}
```

you can recreate your picture with the commands of `LaTeX`. To fixed the cloud you should to see the coordinates `($(#1.south)+(4.2cm,1cm)$)` and `callout relative pointer={(-0.7cm,-0.2cm)}` for the correct positioning that it is depends from the type of equation or list of equations.

[image: C]